# why the results is 200 and then 100?

Tags: java

```
class A implements Runnable {
    static int b = 10;

    public void run() {
        m1();
    }

    public synchronized void m1() {
        b = 100;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public synchronized void m2() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        b = 200;
        System.out.println(b + "m2");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A aa = new A();
        Thread tt = new Thread(aa);
        tt.start();
        aa.m2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it should be 100 followed by 200 (although it may be possible sometimes)?

Comment: It depresses me that this question got an up vote.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you are doing .start() the Thread will be schedule for execution. While the call to aa.m2() is in execution and will be much faster(most of the times).

Answer (score 0):

In `aa.m2` the main thread will call `m2` method directly, so it will be the first to be executed, because the thead `tt` takes little time to initialize and start. `m2` method is synchronized so it will acquire the lock of the object `aa`, then when the thread `tt` has finished initializing it will call `m1` method and wait for the lock of the object `aa` to be released (`m1` method is also synchronized).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I always confuse Thread and it really hard to understand.